Exceed quota on YouTUbe
I keep receiving this error when using YouTube API3
Error uploading video:
 GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.insert failed with error: The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \<a href="/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota"\>quota\</a\> 

And I dont know where to look at.
I basically pick every FileID written down on a spreadsheet, upload them to YouTube, and then print the video ID of the ones that I've just uploaded.  I can upload around three videos, and then the warning sign appears, saying I reached the quota.
I tried looking into google console, but it doesn't seem I have reached. Not sure if I am looking in the correct place. How do I see the amount of quota I am using, and how can I increase it?
// This is the basic idea 
//I get the information to upload the video on youtube
def upload_video(video_file, channel_id, youtube_object):
    try:
        # Define the video metadata
        request_body = {
            'snippet': {
                'title': 'TESTING BY ME',
                'description': 'Your video description',
                'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'],
                'categoryId': '22',  # Set the appropriate category ID
                'channelId': channel_id  # Set the channel ID
            },
            'status': {
                'privacyStatus': 'private'  # Set the privacy status of the video
            }
        }

        # Create a media upload object for the video file
        media = MediaFileUpload(video_file)

        # Execute the video insert request
        response = youtube_object.videos().insert(
            part='snippet,status',
            body=request_body,
            media_body=media
        ).execute()

        # Print the video ID of the uploaded video
        print('Video uploaded. Video ID:', response['id'])
  
    
    // And after uploading, I get the title and video id for every video
    
 
      console.log(`Video ID (${videoId}) and Title (${videoTitle}) written to sheet.`);
  

I have loads of videos to upload on YouTube,they are short ones (less than one minute) and I was trying to use the API to help me with that, but I could only upload three videos with that script.

Side note: the size, length or quality of the video does not matter for quota cost (1600)

To upload requires 1600 quote points if you are still using the development quote of 10k quota points you are not going to be able to upload many videos in a day.
The quota resets at midnight west coast USA
Once you're application is really for production you should apply for a quota increase

Hi there
Just to confirm, in order to increase my quota, should I fill this form: https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form

Yup looks right.   When you fill it out do it like you were talking to you boss.    Give complete truthful information without getting into to much detail
